# Reset globally set routing suffix in symfony routing.yml file

Tags: routes, symfony1, yaml

I am using Symfony 1.3 and I have the following problem:
I need a url in this format www.domain.com/folder (no suffix) however the application sets the default suffix to be .html
Is there a way to override the global suffix in the routing.yml file? I could use mod_rewrite but I would like this link to be able to work without relying on a non-app resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a full stop at the end of the route

Comment: I would have said a period ;-)